set -- arguments with $string and "$string"
Compare $string and "$string":
string="xx yy zz"
if [[ $string == "$string" ]]; then
    echo "Strings are equal."
else
    echo "Strings are not equal."
fi

We get:Strings are equal.
set  -- $string
echo $#
3

To set arguments with $string get 3 arguments.
set  -- "$string"
echo $#
1

To set arguments with "$string" get 1 argument.
What result in this difference?

Quotation marks prevent the string from being split into three separate arguments.

The [[ command takes care of the (missing) quotes. Try set -- $string; if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then …

See Difference between single and double square brackets in Bash.

This difference results because [[ is super very very magic. it is a syntatic sugar in bash handled when parsing the input, not a real command. Inside [[ qoutes have slightly different meaning depending on context. In the case of == , qoutes can be omited, so the strings are equal.
In contrast, the [ or test is a normal command. You can check how the following fails:
[ $string == "$string" ]


[[ is absolutely a real command and not syntactic sugar for anything else. It's just a compound command, which means the entire [[ ... ]] is handled specially, rather than [[ just being the name of a simple command (like [). It's not == that lets you drop quotes. ([[ allows == in place of =, which is true of bash [` as well but not POSIX `[`.)
